# Dropping and reloading layer on Enterprise/SQL Server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

I use ArcPy's `MakeXYEventLayer_management` and `FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` tools to generate a feature class from a CSV file.

I host this layer on a SQL Server Enterprise Geodatabase, and I typically just delete the old feature class and import the new feature class manually using Catalog.

I am wondering about the recommended practices when writing a model or script.

Would it be preferable to use `arcpy.management.DeleteFeatures` for the existing feature class, then `arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToGeodatabase` to reload the new feature?

Comment: I generally try to avoid all the processing overhead, and just load the CSV into a table directly (`arcpy.da.InsertCursor`). If there's a need for continuous access, I load the data into a second table, use SQL to distinguish between inserted, updated, and deleted rows, then apply the changes to the original table. in a single transaction. This way I don't have six-digit ID vales in `SDE.sde_table_registry`. If the feature class can support down time, then TruncateTable and Append can be used to good effect.

Comment: What happened when you tried the alternative method?

Comment: @Vince Using (arcpy.da.InsertCursor) wouldn't update the geometry of the feature class though right?

Comment: InsertCursor doesn't "update" anything, it only INSERTs. Constructing geometries from that which would be an event layer is barely more than a single line of code.